# Custom UIBarButtonItem with interface builder

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used *pushViewController:animated:* method in A UIViewController to go to B UIViewController, and the two UIViewController had selfs xib file.

In system default, I did not need to change anything and I can go back A UIViewController from B UIViewController.

But I want to custom my back button, I use the solution like the follow code:

```
- (void)initBarButton {
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cancel)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;

    UIBarButtonItem *updateButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Update" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(save)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = updateButton;
}

- (void)cancel {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Just like this, but I want to change that in interface builder to modified the xib file to do this. I try to use that like:

[image]

But the system default navigation bar is cover, when I hide the system default bar, the swipe gesture(go back like pop action) also be removed.

Is any possible way to do what I want?

BTW, I used the navigation bar in interface builder with auto layout, how can I let it look like system default navigation bar like this(fill the status bar gap)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Marcus Wu If you want to use XIB instead of storyboard for achieving this, you can see the below steps

```
1.Remove the storyboard from the project
2.Also delete the Main from Main Interface of Deployment Target of Project Target.
3.Now create the New User Interface(View or Empty) and give name as ViewController
4.Then click the Placeholder File Owner with right side Identity Inspector
5.In identity Inspector Custom Class -> Class ->Click the drop down and choose the ViewController.
6.Then Click right side connections inspector.
7.Click the empty circel(name is View) in Outlet.Drag this to the view.I mean you need to press control+emptycircle and drag it to the View. 

8.in appDelegate.h
   Import - #import "ViewController.h"
   @property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *vc;

9.In appDelegate.m
   @synthesize vc;
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
   {
      // Override point for customization after application launch.
      self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
      vc = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
      UINavigationController *navigationVC  = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
      navigationVC.navigationBarHidden = YES;
      self.window.rootViewController = navigationVC;
      self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
      return YES;
   }

10.Now in xib create the custom button Back programmatically or from objects(drag button and give connection)
```

If you use storyboard,you just need to untick the  the shows navigation bar.

```
1.First Click NavigationController in stroyboard
2.Click the Attributes Inspector of Right side
3.Then Click Navigation Controller
4.Inside the Navigation Controller 
     UnTick the Bar Visibility -  Shows Navigation Bar
5.Now create the custom button programmatically or drag it from the Object Library to ViewController in XIB
```